# Unix shell scripting "How to repeat the tasks "

Tags: shell, unix, ksh

I want to repeat the same tasks that were done.

For example:

```
#!/bin/ksh
HOST=`hostname`
#-----------------------------------------
if [ $HOST = "     " ]
cd $path 
ls -lrt
#----------------------------------
read JVM
echo "please opt the JVM "

echo "Do u want to check logs ?.........."
select opt in Yes No
        do
        case $opt in
        "Yes")
commands;
;;

"No")
break
exit 1;
;;
esac
done
```

Here I want to repeat the things by taking the another JVM at the top and I want check logs for different JVM without exiting from the server.

Comment: Which "things" do you want to repeat? Could you indent your code a bit? You could simply put the `read JVM` line between the `"Yes"=` and the `commands;`?

Answer (score 0):

Not at all clear what you are really asking, but I think you are just looking for the following loop:

```
while read JVM; do
...
done
```